# matching problem: generalization

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I know there are quite a few questions on the matching problem but I really cannot understand the solution given by my book.So I am gonna try to explain it step by step and I would ask you if there are any problems with my line of reasoning.

So we have 10 envelopes, 7 red and 3 green, and 10 cards, 7 red and 3 green.What is the probability that exactly k envelops will contain a card with a matching color?

This is the solution:

1. There are $$\binom{10}{7}$$ ways of choosing the seven envelopes into which the red card will be placed.
   This makes sense because I need to find all the possible subsets of seven envelopes I can make.
2. There are $$\binom{7}{j} * \binom{3}{7-j}$$ways of choosing exactly j red envelopes and 7-j green envelopes.Therefore, the probability that exactly j red envelopes will contain red cards is $$\frac{\binom{7}{j} * \binom{3}{7-j}}{\binom{10}{7}}$$
   So this is a little bit trickier: so we have seven red cards and we need to see all the possible subsets we can make considering j red envelops.This is true(as the textbook says) just for j=4,5,6,7 as it would be impossible to match 1 red card with just one red envelope (there will always be at least 4 matches).
3. But if j red envelopes contain red cards, then j-4 green envelopes must also contain green cards.Hence, this is also the probability of exactly $$ k = j + (j-2)= 2j -2\space matches$$
   This part doesn’t make a lot of sense to me (and it definitely should).
   Could someone explain it?

Comment: Just a sidenote for anyone visiting from Google: "the matching problem" can refer to a lot of different problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $j$ red cards are in red envelopes, then $7-j$ red cards are in green envelopes. That leaves $3-(7-j) = j-4$ green envelopes with another kind of card in them: one of the green cards.